# Can we use Tortoise ORM (Python) for QuestDB?

Tags: python, orm, questdb

I want to use QuestDB with Tortoise ORM in my python app. Are the connection params same as a basic PostgreSQL connection?

I want to connect DB like this -

```py
await Tortoise.init({db_url=DATABASE_URL, modules={"models": ["models", "aerich.models"]}})
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the connection parameters for QuestDB are not the same as for PostgreSQL. Use

```
from tortoise import Tortoise

await Tortoise.init(
    db_url='questdb://localhost:8812',  # QuestDB connection string
    modules={'models': ['models']},     # Tortoise models module
)
```